# nagios nrpe plugin: permission issue

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, asterisk, nagios

I have a permission issue that is driving me crazy. I am trying to monitor asterisk on an arch linux virtual machine, using the plugin "check_asterisk_peers". I have installed NRPE (the Nagios remote agent). The relevant section of nrpe.cfg is:

```
command[check_users]=/usr/lib/monitoring-plugins/check_users -w 5 -c 10
command[check_asterisk_peers]=/usr/lib/monitoring-plugins/check_asterisk_peers -p monika_gigaset
```

Here is what I am getting:

```
/usr/lib/monitoring-plugins/check_nrpe -H 10.10.10.10 -c check_users
USERS OK - 2 users currently logged in |users=2;5;10;0
```

Now, this tells me that the NRPE is working all right, and all permissions are set correctly.

If I simply run the plugin (without invoking check_nrpe) I get:

```
aag ~ $ /usr/lib/monitoring-plugins/check_asterisk_peers -p monika_gigaset
CRITICAL: Unable to connect to remote asterisk (does /var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl exist?)
```

however if I run it with sudo it works fine (from which I conclude that the plugin does not have sufficient privileges when run as non-root):

```
aag ~ $ sudo /usr/lib/monitoring-plugins/check_asterisk_peers -p monika_gigaset
 OK: monika_gigaset
```

If I however run the asterisk plugin, I get:

```
aag ~ $ /usr/lib/monitoring-plugins/check_nrpe -H 10.10.10.10 -c check_asterisk_peers
CRITICAL: Unable to connect to remote asterisk (does /var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl exist?)
```

same thing if I run it with sudo:

```
aag ~ $ sudo /usr/lib/monitoring-plugins/check_nrpe -H 10.10.10.10 -c check_asterisk_peers
CRITICAL: Unable to connect to remote asterisk (does /var/run/asterisk/asterisk.ctl exist?)
```

I am certain that the issue is one of permissions, but am unable to solve it. 
The sudoers file (excerpt) reads like:

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
http ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/asterisk -rx database *

nrpe ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service,/usr/lib/monitoring-plugins/check_asterisk_peers
asterisk ALL=(ALL) ALL

%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admins ALL= (ALL) ALL
Defaults targetpw  # Ask for the password of the target user
ALL ALL=(ALL) ALL  # WARNING: only use this together with 'Defaults targetpw'
```

Any hint would be gratefully appreciated! My diagnosis is that the plugin "check_asterisk_peers" does not have the permission to contact asterisk (which runs as root), but I do not understand how I can grant the appropriate permissions to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct solution:

in /etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf 
change owner of socket to

```
[files]
astctlpermissions = 0660
astctlowner = asterisk
astctlgroup = asterisk
```

And add nrpe or nagios user(user you use you can see in nrpe.cfg) to asterisk group.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [manual page](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Telephony/Asterisk/check_asterisk_peers/details) for the plugin, you need to run the plugin with sudo command, therefore you have a successful result when you run the plugin with sudo.

I have highlighted the instructions from the page for you:

To grant the nagios user permissions to execute the script, try something like the following in your /etc/sudoers file:

```
nagios ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/plugins/directory/check_asterisk_peers
```

Then call the plugin using sudo:

```
/path/to/sudo check_asterisk_peers
```

Comment: Thanks Simon. Calling the plugin with sudo indeed works. But the Nagios server calls nrpe, as in 'check_nrpe -H 10.10.10.10 -c check_asterisk_peers'. I am unable to get that part to work. As you see, the sudoers line is already included in my sudoers (except that it says "nrpe" instead of nagios, since nrpe is the daemon in question here).

Comment: I am wondering if you could try to modify the command values with sudo and see if it works, e.g. command[check_asterisk_peers]=/path/to/sudo /usr/lib/monitoring-plugins/check_asterisk_peers -p monika_gigaset

Comment: still no joy.  I entered into nrpe.cfg the following
`command[check_asterisk_peers]=sudo /usr/lib/monitoring-plugins/check_asterisk_peers -p monika_gigaset` and it results into `NRPE: Unable to read output`. However, entering exactly the same command into the command line works just fine! I am starting to despair...

Comment: this will identify me as a total n00b, but so what. The journalctl says: `pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [root]`. I still do not know how to fix it, but I have a hunch that I am getting close...

Comment: I think you can check two places: 1. pass the full path for sudo command, so your command value will change to `<code>command[check_asterisk_peers]=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/lib/monitoring-plugins/check_asterisk_peers -p monika_gigaset`, 2. chcek out the link [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/596614/nagios-nrpe-unable-to-read-output), it said even if you mentioned the NRPE to use different user, for some application will still use nagios user account

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to resolve the issue by granting NOPASSWD to nrpe and its groups. Security is however suboptimal, and may benefit from more restrictive tweaking. Here is the relevant part of sudoers:

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
http ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/asterisk -rx database *
nrpe ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
asterisk ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admins ALL= (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: This one is potentially security hole. Only purpose of nrpe user is isolate nrpe plugins or nrpe deamon from root environment. You drop all that by this sudoers file. With same result you can run nrpe under root user.

Comment: I agree. I was happy to get it up-and-running, but I was unhappy with the security implications.